# How can I make a certain website inaccessible?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [block certain websites from browser](https://superuser.com/questions/47716/block-certain-websites-from-browser)

I want to be able to open "example" from my computer, but I don't want to be able to open "www.example.com". Is this possible?

Comment: can you get to http://www.iana.org/domains/example/ ? thats where www.example.com redirects to.

Comment: this `www.example.com` is just example :) ok I want  block for example `facebook.com`. how can make this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add it to your "hosts" file to block it:

http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm

Comment: Beat me by 28 seconds.

Comment: Haha, yeah I can't believe how three people came up with the same thing that quickly... Edit: 4! Edit: 5!!!

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bunch of people had a go at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your hosts file:
127.0.0.1 facebook.com

This should prevent your browser from doing a DNS lookup on the site, and instead point it at your computer's loopback address.  If your computer is running IIS and has a default website, you'll get that, if not you will get an error that the page cannot be found/displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts with Notepad and add the following entries to it:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

So all traffic to that sites will be redirected to your computer

Answer (score 0):

Open the "hosts" file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc with Notepad (Windows 7). At the bottom of the text on a blank line add "127.0.0.1 www.example.com" without the quotations and then save the file. When you go to www.example.com it should no longer work.
http://www.timeatlas.com/term_to_learn/general/taking_control_with_the_hosts_file

Comment: Also, some ROUTERs have parental controls features within the web interface. Sometimes you can add websites you want to block within the router configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line to your hosts file. This file is located in:

```
C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Open it with notepad and add lines like so:

```
127.0.0.1      example.com
127.0.0.1      Facebook.com
```

Make sure that you do not rename the hosts file when you are saving it. It is normal for it to have no extension.

Comment: When I am trying save modified `host` file, I obtain this popup window: `Please check if this file is opened in another program` and changes is not saved.  I am close all programs (included browsers) but when trying save changes, result again none.