# How do I block myself from time-eating websites?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browsing

I want to block my Mac (running Snow Leopard) at work from accessing sites like Facebook and reddit.

there are browser extensions, but I'm worried about security – I get nervous allowing them to "access my data on all websites".

Is there a simple direct way to do it?

My main browser is Google Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I block certain websites from being accessed through a browser?](http://superuser.com/questions/47716/how-do-i-block-certain-websites-from-being-accessed-through-a-browser)

Comment: @ChrisF Those are both primarily (or exclusively, given the answers?) for Windows.

Comment: @slhck - damn. Missed the osx tag. Feel free to ignore the suggestions then.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your `hosts` file with this free and time saving utility:

[Gas Mask](https://code.google.com/p/gmask/)

[image: Gas Mask]

You can have two profiles, for work and home. So you can switch with one click from one profile to another.

Answer (score 2):

I use Firefox and block time wasting website using LeechBlock.

You put which website that you want to block, when you want to block, and the duration. The add-on will monitor how long you visit that site, and block if you are going beyond your limit. It is not accessing any website, just monitoring the URL bar for address.

Take a look at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Open `Applications/Utilities/Terminal` and type the following (it will ask you to enter admin password because it is a system file)

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/hosts
   ```
2. Type in the website you want to block in the following format:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 www.xxx.com
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> and press <kbd>Y</kbd> on your keyboard to save the modified buffer, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Save the file with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and the return key  to go back to Terminal.
5. Clear your DNS cache by using following command

   ```
   sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
   ```

The websites will be blocked.

Comment: "*Open `'Applications/Utilities/Terminal` and type the following*" … what should the OP type?

Comment: I cleared up your post, it contained a few formatting errors and wrong statements. `nano etc/hosts` won't work, you need a slash before `/etc`. Also, restarting the machine is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Block it in `/private/etc/hosts`.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
```

You can edit this file by calling:

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /private/etc/hosts
```

Comment: i can find /private/etc/host but i'm not quite sure what you mean me to add

Comment: is the effect of this to redirect me to me local host instead of the external IP address if i try to access facebook?

Comment: Exactly, it will try to reach localhost instead of facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use http://www.persistence-app.com

It will block the sites you visit on all browsers

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer to your question is StayFocusd, an app for Google Chrome. It's purposefully designed for your application and will allow you a short period every day on your "time wasting" websites (default 15 minutes I think).

You can configure it to only disable the sites during work hours, so you can continue using them after hours. There's other useful features as well.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en